# Identify Caller Object

Tags: c++, oop

**Update**: The below scenario can be achieved simply by **this** pointer but I was wondering if there is an alternate way. I have simplified the requirement for question purposes. But in jist the question is after submitting a member variable of the caller class to another callee class, does the callee class has any way to keep track of the    [ caller instance <--> caller member] variable pair.

Let's say I have `Class Callee` and `Class Caller`. `Class Caller` registers its member variable `dummy` to `Class Callee` using `Class Callee`'s Method. Now `Class Caller` calls `Class Callee`'s method again. 
`Class Callee` has to identify the caller instance and return the `dummy` variable value.

Is there a way to identify the caller object? Or one needs to assign an id to caller class first time and there on whenever caller calls again caller needs to use that id?

Pseudo Code:

```
class Callee {
    Callee : id(0) {}

    void AddVariable(Data dummy) {
        std::pair<int, Data> p;
        p.first = id;
        p.second = dummy;
    }

    Data GetVariable() {
        //Find the variable, process it and return 
    }

private:
    std::set<std::pair<int, Data>> dummy_list;
    int id;
}



class Caller {
    Caller {
        m_callee->AddVariable(dummy);
    }

    void SomeFunc() {
        std::cout << m_a->GetVariable() << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Data dummy;
    Callee* m_callee;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to identify the calling class or the calling object?

Comment: Can you please specify more what you want to achieve?

Comment: My bad, the object instance. For identifying purpose when more than one instance of Class B registers its member variable dummy. Class B has to check from a list of dummy variable and return appropriate.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to achieve.  Please edit the question to include whatever code you have so far, so we can get some idea of what class A and class B are trying to do here.  Use pseudo-code if needed, but it'll make answering this a lot more likely.

Comment: The use case is for server design:

Server Class -> Creates one universal Manager instance and Connection instance per connection 

Connection Class -->  This handles the messages, puts them in queue etc. Also it registers this queue to Manager Class

Manager Class --> Worker thread impl, deque the messages and 
calls Library

Now I want to implement Lock/Unlock for Library i.e Connection Instance can call lock/unlock method of Manager Class. Now manager depending on which instance called lock should execute messages for that connection and stop execution for other connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without telling A what instance is calling this problem is insoluble; C++ does not provide such information. And even then you have to trust that the provided instance is correct (that is, there is no protection against actively malicious code in this circumstance).

Comment: This is about it.  Assuming class A is the Manager, and class B in the connection instance, every time B calls into A, it'll need to include `this` as a parameter.  That will then let the Manager always be able to identify which connection instance is calling.

Comment: How would i identify the variable dummy (which was saved earlier for this instance) from  a list of variables using this pointer? 
Perhaps keeping a std::map<id, variable> but then the problem boils down to getting the correct id from this pointer. This information is not saved anywhere and hence the caller should identify itself with the id. Am I correct?

PS. I don't want to do this->variable